# Maxium GCD of pair number in array

Tags: java

I want  to find maxium GCD of pair number in array
Example : 2,4,7,9,14,15
Output: 7

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int[] nums = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int result = findMaxGCD(nums);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int findMaxGCD(int[] arr) {
        int maxGCD = 0;
        int n = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                int gcd = gcd(arr[i], arr[j]);
                if (gcd > maxGCD) {
                    maxGCD = gcd;
                }
            }
        }

        return maxGCD;
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

I test my solution but It have a runtime problem, it is timeout. Can you help me save more time.

Best Solution.It have a runtime problem, it is timeout. Can you help me save more time.

Comment: Are you running this on a local computer?

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you opened a scanner object, read a number, then print the result, but you have to close the `Scanner` object at the end.

Add `sc.close()` after reading the input.

Comment: I add this to my code, but result does not change, I think i need new way, but i cant find it.